# Are questions exploring constructive analysis on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Meta,

I'm not a professional. I've been reading Bishop. I have questions. They are likely fairly basic to a professional. Am I on topic here, or should I wander over to the other site?

Comment: My educated guess is that the users around here most likely in a position to answer your questions are also likely to entertain the question and not shut it down. Just make sure they are clear, precise, and focused (and hopefully not due to some undergraduate-type confusion about logic). Something a graduate student encountering Bishop might ask, for example.

Comment: The/A question got asked http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155717/bishops-paradox-of-the-countability-of-sequences

Comment: Take care, though.  It is a question-and-answer forum.  Not a discussion forum.  Not an opinion forum.

Comment: I am well aware of the general principles of the network.

Comment: Probably better to join the [Constructive News Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/constructivenews), where you will meet both followers of Bishop and people with different views on constructive mathematics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a broad perspective, questions about the mathematics of constructive systems are on topic. Of course, particular questions could be off topic for a number of reasons. In particular, it is easy to create questions which come down to subjective opinion, and those questions are not on topic. But nontrivial questions about the mathematics of these systems seem to receive answers and upvotes.